# Pass values to java applet param

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, applet, param

I am using a java applet inside an aspx page in Visual Studio 2010 in .NET web site. The code for the applet class is in jar files. One of the jars is TestJar.jar that has com.software.TestAppletClass class that has functionality for playing a wav file (the path is specified in testURL param of the applet tag).

```
<applet 
CODE="com.software.TestAppletClass"
CODEBASE="./codebase"
mayscript="true"
ARCHIVE="TestJar.jar"
NAME="TestName"
WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="90">
        <param name="testURL" value="./uploads/temp.wav">
        <param name="autoPlay" value="No">
      </applet>
```

For right now the value of the sampleURL param of the applet is hard-coded.

I want to be able to play any wav file using the applet. Is there any way to pass a variable to sampleURL param? (using javascript or cs file)

Regards,
Julia

Comment: Is the above comment what you've attempted to do, or is it a solution that solved your problem?  If it's the former, you should your question to include the additional information, and if it's the latter, you should actually add it as an answer to your own question (with a little more detail as to what it represents).

Comment: Hi Derek, that was what I tried to do. That was not a solution. I included that code sample in the question itself.